# Electron Uncaught Error: \\?\ .. node_sleep.node is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: node.js, electron

I just wanted to call function from Electron app and here remoteModules.js is for these exports functions. The problem is, I got a mysterious error `Uncaught Error: \\?` on the Electron app developer console. And the error seems caused by `require('sleep');` lines. Not only sleep module, I also tried `require('better-sqlite3');` and I confirmed I get the same error, so I think I can assume this error caused when requiring a npm installed module. So, what is this, and how can I bypass this bug to import modules successfully? Thanks.

index.html:

```js
const remoteModules = require('electron').remote.require('./remoteModules')
console.log("remoteModules.tmp:", remoteModules.tmp(3))

.. more code
```

remoteModules.js:

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

// # I tried all of these and got the same or similar error 
// var sleep = require('sleep');
// var sleep = require(path.join(__dirname, 'sleep'));
// var sleep = require(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules\\sleep\\build\\Release\\node_sleep.node'));
// var sleep = require(path.join(__dirname, 'C:/pg/electron/note_system_ui/node_modules/sleep/build/Release/node_sleep.node'));
// var sleep = require(path.join(__dirname, 'C:\\pg\\electron\\note_system_ui\\node_modules\\sleep\\build\\Release\\node_sleep.node'));
// var sleep = require( 'C:\\pg\\electron\\note_system_ui\\node_modules\\sleep\\build\\Release\\node_sleep.node' );
// var sleep = require( 'C:/pg/electron/note_system_ui/node_modules/sleep/build/Release/node_sleep.node' );

.. more code
```

full error:

```
Uncaught Error: \\?\C:\pg\electron\note_system_ui\node_modules\sleep\build\Release\node_sleep.node is not a valid Win32 application.
```

versions:

```
"dependencies": {
    "better-sqlite3": "^7.1.2",
    "electron": "^11.1.1",
    "sleep": "^6.3.0"
  },
```

Comment: I think there are some points missing in your question that would really help with understanding the problem: which platform are you running on? Did you consider, that node API is not available in the renderer process without taking extra action? (although you would have seen something like `require` not found). Is the regular node `require`  on those modules working in the main process?